# How do I make command blocks distinguish between an in ground arrow and in ground tipped arrow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to make explosive arrow, but I want to have only strong harming arrows explode; the command is:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={inGround: 1b}] run summon tnt ~ ~ ~
```

I have tried to add a "CostumPotionEffect" nbt, but it doesn't explode the strong harming arrows i take from the creative inventory; how can I fix the command?

Comment: What was the command you are using to try to detect the modified arrows?

Comment: Did you misspell CustomPotionEffect?  In your question it is misspelled.  The "o" and the "u" are flipped.